# Centering div in parent div when both have position absolute

Tags: javascript, css

I generate my components dynamically with JS, using position: absolute for both parent's and children, as this gets the placement how I want it.

However, every solution I've seen for centering a div within a div requires position of one to be relative, is there a way around this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: *requires position of one to be relative,* --> position:absolute will also do the job on the parent so the solution you found should work .. if not show us

Comment: you could center using FlexBox and no position: absolute at all

Answer (score 0):

Starting from two divs:

```
<div id="div1">
  div 1
  <div id="div2">
    div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

with jquery:

```
let offset = $('#div1').width() / 2 - $('#div2').width() / 2;
$('#div2').css('left', parseInt(offset) + 'px');
```

without jquery:

```
let offset = (document.getElementById("div1").clientWidth / 2) - (document.getElementById("div2").clientWidth / 2);
document.getElementById("div2").style.left = parseInt(offset) + 'px';
```

Answer (score -2):

You can apply the following CSS to your 2nd div to get it centered.

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

However, this will only work with relatively modern browsers. 'transform' is a CSS3 property.

Comment: Setting the left value will still be relying on the parent div to have a position of relative, otherwise it will set it to 50% of the first parent div of that element that is relatively positioned.

Comment: Are you sure? Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to be working here. Maybe my context is different.
https://codepen.io/makingutopia/pen/QWWqLwz